# Check date between two other dates spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have this model:

```
public class Event {
    private String name;
    private Date start;
    private Date end;
}
```

and repository as

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {
    List<Event> findByEventTypeAccount(Account account);
}
```

What I want to do is, I will pass one date and need to check that date is between `start` and `end` e.g. (I will pass Sept 30 as date and need to find all entries which have Sept 30 between their `start` and `end`)

Something like `findDateisBetweenStartAndEnd(Date date)`?

Comment: You should take a look the reference documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation. It's well explained.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You should take a look [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html#jpa.query-methods.query-creation). It's well explained.

In your case, I think you cannot use between because you need to pass two parameters

> **Between** - findByStartDateBetween … where x.startDate between ?1 and ?2

In your case take a look to use a combination of `LessThan` or `LessThanEqual` with `GreaterThan` or `GreaterThanEqual`

- **LessThan/LessThanEqual**

> LessThan - findByEndLessThan … where x.start< ?1
>
> LessThanEqual findByEndLessThanEqual … where x.start <= ?1

- **GreaterThan/GreaterThanEqual**

> GreaterThan - findByStartGreaterThan … where x.end> ?1
>
> GreaterThanEqual - findByStartGreaterThanEqual … where x.end>= ?1

You can use the operator `And` and `Or` to combine both.

Comment: Hi will this be possible with String Values? So for example with a table of persons and select all between lastname = "abcd" to lastname= "efgh"

Comment: @Pau Shouldn't the method names be `findByStartLessThan\Equal` and `findByStartGreaterThan\Equal` so it corresponds with the JPQL (i.e. `where x.start <\= ?1`and `where x.end >\= ?1`)?

Comment: can you please tell me which format of date you are passing from client to call controller of method findDateisBetweenStartAndEnd?? I stuck with format part when i submit the request through client for the endpoint.

Comment: how to add where condition on another attribute ? between and where together in single query in spring data jpa?

Answer (score 70):

I did use following solution to this:

```
findAllByStartDateLessThanEqualAndEndDateGreaterThanEqual(OffsetDateTime endDate, OffsetDateTime startDate);
```

Comment: You you please add a little (more detailed) explanation?

Comment: but for that you should pass two dates the start and the end one, I think is the right approach

Comment: The order of the prams is wrong. First, param is related to startDate, not endDate

Comment: @JordanSilva , the order of params is correct as it tests is onу period cross over other one but not is the other period entirely inside the checking period.

Comment: In this case instead use this method too long, use a @query annotation, is more usefull to undestand your code, your mode works, just an advice.

Answer (score 35):

You can also write a custom query using `@Query`

```
@Query(value = "from EntityClassTable t where yourDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
public List<EntityClassTable> getAllBetweenDates(@Param("startDate")Date startDate,@Param("endDate")Date endDate);
```

Edit: For LocalDateTime I just tried this solution for filtering record based on date and type in spring JPA:

```
Page<MyEntity> findMyEntityByEntityDateBetweenAndType(
            @Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate,
            @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate, @Param("type") String type, Pageable pageable);
```

Here EntityDate can be like CreatedDate,ModifiedDate etc.

Comment: how will it handle null start and end date?

Answer (score 6):

You can use JpaRepository

```
List<Entity> findByColumnDateBetween(LocalDateTime to, LocalDateTime from);
```

Comment: why in reverse order (to,from) instead of (from,to) ?

Comment: @Ranjithkumar maybe because some people love dancing moonwalk ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try

`List<Article> findAllByPublicationDate(Date publicationDate);`

The detail could be checked in this article:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query-by-date

Comment: This is a combination of unexplained code and a link. Please add an explanation of how the code works and how it is supposed to solve the problem. Without such an explanation, your post spreads the misconception that StackOverflow is a platform for peddling unpaind programming work. Linking externally is not considered such an explanation. Link only answer might get deleted.