# Spring JPA get dates between a range (inclusive) in mongo with LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

Very similar to this question: [Check date between two other dates spring data jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784344/check-date-between-two-other-dates-spring-data-jpa)

However, I am attempting to do this with MongoDB and `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

I have tried:

- `findAllByMetadataStartTimeBetween(start, end)` (works, but exclusive start/end)
- `findAllByMetadataStartTimeGreaterThanEqual(start)` (works, but no end)

However, when I try: `findAllByMetadataStartTimeGreaterThanEqualAndMetadataStartTimeLessThanEqual(start,end)`

I get the error: `json can't serialize type : class java.time.LocalDateTime`

Any idea why this particular combination throws this error, when the previous ones do not?

Comment: A simple `hack` is to while passing dates to the between method subtract 1 from smaller date  and add 1 to the bigger date

Comment: that's a decent idea for a workaround if I can't crack this error. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code. I am sure, works for inclusive

```
@Query("{'dateTime' : { $gte: ?0, $lte: ?1 } }")
List<YourObject> findByDateTimeBetween(Date from, Date to);
```

Spring data method signature below works for exclusive

```
public List<YourObject> findByDateBetween(Date from, Date to);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make custom query:

```
Query query = new Query(
      new Criteria().andOperator(
    Criteria.where("metadataStartTime").gte(start),
    Criteria.where("metadataStartTime").lte(end)
  )
);

return mongoTemplate.find(query, EntityName.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA "Between" method is inclusive. The problem is probably with the precision of your Date Object.

Try to make sure The compared start date has the **exact hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.** Even if is the searched data is some milliseconds ahead it won't be caught by the query.

In my case, when I set them all for start date to 00:00:00.000, and for the end date to 23:59:59.999  The JPA findAllByMetadataStartTimeBetween(start, end) **works fine and inclusive**.

Comment: I would not say it is inclusive :) I even fetched `seconds` from `Instant` (so the query is like `findAllByTime_SecondsBetween(from, to)` and it still does not work as expected. With subtraction and addition of one second to the period, it does.

Comment: @WitoldKupś Maybe you missed the millisecond part.