# Iterate through a repository to access certain information

Tags: java, sql, loops, spring-boot, repository

In my Java/Spring application I am trying to iterate through all items found in the SQL Database Table called License, and send an email if the licence expiration date is 30 days away from today, but I am having issues iterating through.

The issue is accessing the expiration column. What should I be doing to access the expiration date of each license in the database, because clearly the way I am doing it is not accurate. I might be getting confused because you need to get all the items from the table through the repository but then for each item you use the model to get access the Expiration date.

Is there a better way to iterate through the list of items in a repository and access specific columns? Or can someone easily help me fix the code I have so far?

```html
List<License> licenses=licenseRepository.findAll();
for(Object lic:licenses){

    if (lic.expiration.minusDays(30) == LocalDate.now()) {
        try {
            emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mail, licenseModel);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create custom SQL query which will find all licenses with expiration equals  30 days away. If you're using Spring Boot Data you can use @Query annotation in your repository interface.

Comment: Take a look at this post if you are using Spring Data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784344/check-date-between-two-other-dates-spring-data-jpa

Comment: Actually with spring data you can create metod in repository with specific name which Will find match rows

Answer (score 0):

## Repository

> better way to iterate through the list of items in a repository and access specific columns

Nope. We cannot help you on that point as you have not shown or explained your repository code.

I can show you proper [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) code to retrieve a date-only value from a database column of a type akin to the SQL-standard `DATE` type.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

> Or can someone easily help me fix the code I have so far?

Yes, I can help.

- You are using incorrect syntax.
- You are ignoring crucial issue of time zone.

## Use `isEqual` method, not `==`

The `==` operator on Java tests either:

- If two references both point to the same object, to the same location in memory.
  (Generally speaking, this is very rarely needed in most apps. So generally **do not use `==` with objects**.)
- If two primitives (`int`, `boolean`, etc.) have equivalent values.

So the effect is dramatically different between those two. One compares the values of the data you care about (in primitives). The other compares the memory location (a number basically) of a pair of references ([pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming))) **without regard to the data** you care about (in objects).

When comparing the *value* of two objects, call a method. For `LocalDate` that would be [`isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)). You can also compare temporally with [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)) & [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)).

So your code:

```
if ( lic.expiration.minusDays( 30 ) == LocalDate.now() ) { … }
```

…should be…

```
if ( lic.expiration.minusDays( 30 ).isEqual( LocalDate.now() ) ) { … }
```

I would break that down in my own code.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
LocalDate thirtyDaysBeforeExpiration = lic.expiration.minusDays( 30 ) ;
if ( thirtyDaysBeforeExpiration.isEqual( today ) ) { … }
```

## Time zone

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

So my version of your code would actually be:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate thirtyDaysBeforeExpiration = lic.expiration.minusDays( 30 ) ;
if ( then.isEqual( today ) ) { … }
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).