# How to get list of objects with created_at time from yesterday till now

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a list "BonusHistory" with many objects, which I find by "bonus id"

```
List<BonusHistory> bonusHistories = bonusHistoryRepository.findAllByBonusIdAndDeletedAtIsNull(id);
```

Now I need to get from these list, objects which were created from (yesterday, last week, last month) till now. Maybe i need to change query in repository, idk.
I am sorry if I explained incomprehensibly (i'm newbie in programming)

Comment: *Maybe i need to change query in repository* I think you should, with a parameter for the minimum date required. Histories tend to get long, this way you always fetch the whole table. put an index on the relevant field (creationTimestamp or whatever) in the history table.

Comment: Check this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784344/check-date-between-two-other-dates-spring-data-jpa

Comment: you should custom your query to get your query by Date

Comment: i already have created_at field

Answer (score 1):

You should have Data field like creationDate in BonusHistory and after it, you will be able to customize your query

Comment: so you can create method List<BonusHistory> findAllByCreatedAtBetween(Date date1, Date date2)

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution, you can just add you created_id clause in the method like:

```
List<BonusHistory> bonusHistories = bonusHistoryRepository.findAllByBonusIdAndDeletedAtIsNullAndCreatedIdAfter(id,your_date_range);
```

For a more sophisticated solution, you can write a native query and perform the date operation as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827754/3519504).

Answer (score 0):

My objects already contains "created_at" fields

Comment: This is not an answer if you want to make a statement put it in the question itself.